# Storing and retrieving image using path to stored file as String

Tags: ios, swift, image, filepath, nsfilemanager

I'm using Realm and storing the file path to captured images as `String`s. I want to retrieve them later for use in a tableView. Here's my code to store the path for each image:

```
func saveImage(imageName: String){
    //create an instance of the FileManager
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    //get the image path
    thisImagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(imageName)
    //get the image taken with camera
    let image = originalCapturedImage
    //get the PNG data for this image
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
    //store it in the document directory
    fileManager.createFile(atPath: thisImagePath as String, contents: data, attributes: nil)

    print("Picture path at assignment \n")

    print(thisImagePath as Any)

}
```

And here's the code to retrieve the image:

```
    ...
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsPath = paths[0] //Get the docs directory
        let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).appendingPathComponent(item.picPath).path
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)

    print("Picture path at retrieval \n")

    print(item.picPath as Any)


    cell.imageWell.image = image
    cell.imageWell.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}
```

Here's the comparison of the file path at runtime:

```
Picture path at assignment 

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0E9CACAD-C6B3-4F6C-B0DB-72C43AC722E1/Documents/1535219147
...
...
Picture path at retrieval 

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0E9CACAD-C6B3-4F6C-B0DB-72C43AC722E1/Documents/1535219147
```

The paths appear identical to me, yet no image appears. I've searched all over SO, and at one point came across a mention of the use of the `URL` for the file path. Somehow, I lost track of that entry and haven't been able to find it again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code for writing the image to the file instead of creating  file with content.         `try? data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath))`

You can also refer below code for saving image.

```
class func saveImageToFileWithDirectory(_ imageData:Data, fileName:String, folderName : String? = nil) {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths.object(at: 0) as! NSString
    let path = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(folderName) as NSString
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path as String) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: path as String, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    let imagePath = path.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: imagePath as String) {
        try? imageData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath))
    } }
```

Code for retrieving the image looks good. If you need help in that also, pls comment, I will post that also.

Hope this solves your issue.